# javascript: find the prototype object to which a property belongs

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype-chain

I have an instance from Square which inherits from Rectangle

```
instance instanceof Rectangle --> true
instance instanceof Square    --> true
instance.area() ; // --> area is defined by Rectangle
```

Now, in my code I don't know where the 'area' function is defined and I want the prototype object which defines it. Of course I can traverse the prototype chain (not tested)

```
var proto = instance ;
while( !(proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto)).hasOwnProperty('area') ) {}
// do something with 'proto'
```

However, I was wondering if there is a better/faster way to get the prototype object to which a function belongs ?

Comment: I can't think of an easier way to determine this then traversing to prototype chain. But may I ask you, what the purpose is of determine this?

Comment: I'm writing a function called $super, which calls the overridden function, something like "area: function(){ return this.$super }". Inside this $super function I need to traverse the prototype chain to look for the next definition of area

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri You don't need to traverse the entire prototype chain in that case. Simply do `Object.getPrototypeOf(this).area()` from within a method of the derived instance. BTW are you the guy who forked my [`augment`](https://github.com/javascript/augment) library?

Comment: Object.getPrototypeOf(this).area() will not work (I think), because if you have for example this situation: http://jsfiddle.net/jeanluca/aECvz/ you need inside each $super call to know where you are in the prototype chain, so you can call the next 'func', because 'this' is always the same (C). 
Yes I forked you, VERY interesting code, but I've now started from scratch because I want to do it differently ( http://bit.ly/1d9WDgB - prototypal-inheritance.js, note that it doesn't work yet!)

Comment: here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jeanluca/a6FJz/1/ (the code comes from here: bit.ly/1d9WDgB)

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri You can achieve what you're trying to do very easily. See this [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BuujS/). The `super` function is implemented in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/aaditmshah/6241369 "A simple implementation of `super` in JavaScript.").

Comment: See also [Determine origin of method in prototype chain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29849959/1048572)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. There isn't. You have to traverse the prototype chain:

```
function owner(obj, prop) {
    var hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
    while (obj && !hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop))
        obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
    return obj;
}
```

Now you simply do:

```
var obj = owner(instance, "area");
console.log(obj === Rectangle);    // true
```

If `instance` or its prototypes do not have the property `area` then `owner` returns `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Replying to you comment: What you essentially seem to want is to call a function of the base class inside the overriding function of an inherited class.

I wouldn't bother with the prototype chain in your case, you can just build `base` into your inheritance model:

```
function Rectangle() {}
Rectangle.prototype.area = function () {
    console.log("rectangle");
};

//setting up inheritance
function Square() {}
Square.prototype = Object.create(Rectangle.prototype);
Square.prototype.base = Rectangle.prototype;

Square.prototype.area = function () {
    this.base.area();
    console.log("square");
};

var square = new Square();
square.area();
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XqVZW/)**

Comment: That is indeed what I'm trying here bit.ly/1d9WDgB (how can I make a link in a comment?) The problem is more complex than you thing though. Checkout this FiDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/jeanluca/uWDYX/. Also when you uncomment the code in the middle, you'll see that your context/this is changing!

Comment: In your fiddle, what output would be desired in the line `Base, multi = 2`?

Comment: this.multi should be 3, so I would expect the outcome to be 90 (3 * (3 * 10)) (I just found out how to make a link in a comment :). Of course it can be possible that Base represents an abstract last, and doesn't define a 'multi' at all!

Comment: In this case you have to call the `base` function with the correct context. You can use `bind` to do that: http://jsfiddle.net/uWDYX/1/

Comment: that works, but now I've removed the commented code, and it doesn't work anymore ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeanluca/uWDYX/2/)). Note that instead of using **bind** you can use **call**

Comment: You're right about `call`! Well now it creates an infinite loop because the context of `this` never changes. So it calles the same function again and again. Hmm... try this: http://jsfiddle.net/uWDYX/3/ I added an optional argument to `getValue` that lets you override the current multi value.

Comment: yep, that works, I think however that this is not how inheritance is meant. You really need to have the same context everywhere. Furthermore, if we continue this discussion we probably end up with something similar as [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jeanluca/a6FJz/1/)