# Determine origin of method in prototype chain

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

Lets say that i have the following prototype-chain.

```
function Vehicle() {}
Vehicle.prototype.drive = function() { console.log("I'm driving"); };
Vehicle.prototype.turnOn = function() { console.log("Wrom wrom"); }; 

function Car() {}
Car.prototype = new Vehicle();
Car.prototype.honkHorn = function() { console.log("*loud sound*"); };

var car = new Car();
```

I'm iterating over the `car`-object with a `for`-loop and want to determine which object the method origins from like so:

```
for (var prop in car) {
    console.log(car[prop].nameOfItsOrigin);
}
```

The outcome i am hoping for is a list of the methods origin like so:

```
Vehicle
Vehicle
Car
```

Comment: Objects don't have names. So what exactly do you want the output to be?

Comment: But if i access `__proto__` on my `car`-object i can see the specific methods on that object, and if i look into the next `__proto__` i can see the `Vehicle`-object. How come i cannot fetch their names that way?

Comment: That's just some `console.log` magic that uses something like `.constructor.name`

Comment: That was actually my first idea but `console.log(car[prop].constructor.name);` just returns `Function`

Comment: Wouldn't the output be Vehicle, Vehicle, Car?

Comment: It would, thanks for clearing that up @AlvaroMontoro

Comment: Not that it helps you much with an answer :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the object from which a property is inherited by traversing the prototype chain:

```
function origin(obj, prop) {
    for (; obj != null; obj=Object.getPrototypeOf(prop))
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop))
            return obj;
    return obj;
}
// or, recursively:
function origin(obj, prop) {
    if (obj == null || Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop))
        return obj;
    return origin(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj), prop);
}
```

Then you can do

```
for (var p in car)
    console.log(p, origin(car, p), origin(car, p).constructor.name)
```

```
honkHorn, {…}, Car
drive, {…}, Vehicle
turnOn, {…}, Vehicle
```

Comment: (`.constructor.name` requires correct inheritance though: `Car.prototype = Object.create(Vehicle.prototype, {constructor: {value:Car}});`)

Comment: Thank you very much! But why is it necessary to specify the constructor?

Comment: Because otherwise `origin(car, "constructor")` is `Vehicle.prototype` :-)